Machine learning-does repeatedly training on data cause overfit?
So I have a machine learning model that has been trained and there is no overfit or underfit, this model is perfect and can detect objects correctly. However, after that I try what if I train this model again repeatedly and what happens is that overfit occurs, does training a model repeatedly on a model that is already perfect can affect the model? So what was originally normal becomes overfit.
I hope to get an explanation about my case

Training a machine learning (ML) model repeatedly could lead to model overfit. That's why you need to estimate the best epochs (number of iterations to train the model with same data).
One of the way that I use to analyze and determine how many epochs I need to train a model is by using graphs to compare epochs, model accuracy and model loss. Look at the graphs below.

n of epochs and model accuracy
n of epochs and model loss

You can tell if the model is already overfit or still in underfit stage if the model accuracy is not significanly increasing or the model loss is not significantly decreasing.
